# MySQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-insert

I get this error message from mySQL:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key,time) 
VALUES ('FreeTest','86400')' at line 2
```

Here is the code:

```
if ((isset($_POST['key'])) && (isset($_POST['days']))) {

  $key = mysql_escape_string($_POST['key']);
  $days = mysql_escape_string($_POST['days'] * 86400);

  $add = "INSERT INTO licence
  (key,time)
  VALUES
  ('$key','$days')";

  $addkey = mysql_query($add);
}
```

Comment: You can't use mysql keyword `key` as a bare column name for a mysql table.  You could escape them with back tics (aka Grave accents), but that is extremely tacky.  Just don't use these words: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The column named `KEY`, which is one of the column names, **happens to be a reserved keyword**, you need to escape with backticks so you won't get syntax error, `TIME` is also a reserved keyowrd but mysql permits it to be used without backticks.

```
INSERT INTO licence (`key`,time) VALUES ('$key','$days')
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)